# windows 7 does not boot after debian install

Tags: linux, windows

I installed linux debian as a 2nd system and it works fine, however when I choose Windows in loader(lilo) to boot, it stops on a windows logo.

I tried to boot in safe mode, and it stops on classpnp.sys driver.
I'm not sure whether the problem is in classpnp or in some other driver which is failed to load after it.
I also tried to boot with bootlog (ntbtlog), however it is not created (I check C:\Windows).

It seems like smth is wrong with hard drive configuration with several partitions.
I've googled a lot of similiar issues with classpnp.sys, but none of the solutions helped:
-I tried to change bios SATA coniguration from IDE to AHCI,
-restore backup configuration files (SAM, DEFAULT, SECURITY etc).

If anyone knows what else can I do with this, please help.

Comment: This question belongs on superuser.com, this may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface#Boot_issues

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on super user, but you need to press F8 and select safe mode. There you can fix your problems